# Multiple running totals for win/loss - Aggregate Function?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table of sales opportunities within BigQuery that looks something like this:

```
Opp ID  Created-Date  Amount  IsWon  IsLoss  DateWon     DateLost
------  ------------  ------  -----  ------  -------     --------
001     2019-01-01    60000   FALSE  FALSE   null        null
002     2019-01-02    75000   TRUE   FALSE   2019-02-20  null
003     2019-02-01    30000   FALSE  FALSE   null        null
004     2019-02-02    35000   FALSE  TRUE    null        2019-03-01
005     2019-03-01    50000   FALSE  FALSE   null        null
006     2019-04-01    10000   FALSE  FALSE   null        null
```

Effectively, what I want to do is have three running tallies: open, won and closed per month. However, I'm stumped as won/losses need to be subtracted from the open tally as they are won/lost. I'd expect the final table to look like:

```
Month    Open     Won     Loss
-----    ----     ---     ----
2019-01  135000   0       0
2019-02  125000   75000   0
2019-03  140000   75000   35000
2019-04  150000   75000   35000
```

I'm sure this can be done using aggregate functions and `PARTITION`ing, but I'm still too much of a SQL noob to wrap my head around the *how*.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT id, amount, isWon, isLoss,
    DATE_TRUNC(Created_Date, MONTH) AS open_month,
    DATE_TRUNC(DateWon, MONTH) AS win_month,
    DATE_TRUNC(DateLost, MONTH) AS lost_month
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), months AS (
  SELECT month FROM (
    SELECT MIN(month) min_month, MAX(month) max_month FROM (
      SELECT open_month month FROM temp UNION ALL
      SELECT win_month FROM temp UNION ALL
      SELECT lost_month  FROM temp 
  )) t, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(t.min_month, max_month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
), totals AS (SELECT open_month AS month, SUM(amount) total FROM temp GROUP BY open_month
), wins AS (SELECT win_month  AS month, SUM(amount) won FROM temp WHERE IsWon GROUP BY win_month
), losses AS (SELECT lost_month AS month, SUM(amount) loss FROM temp WHERE IsLoss GROUP BY lost_month
)
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', month) AS month, 
  SUM(total - IFNULL(won, 0) - IFNULL(loss, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY month) total, 
  SUM(IFNULL(won, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY month) won, 
  SUM(IFNULL(loss, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY month) loss 
FROM months m
LEFT JOIN totals t USING (month)
LEFT JOIN wins w USING (month)
LEFT JOIN losses l USING (month)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row month   total   won     loss     
1   2019-01 135000  0       0    
2   2019-02 125000  75000   0    
3   2019-03 140000  75000   35000    
4   2019-04 150000  75000   35000
```

Note: while above solution looks wordy - it actually gives you expected and correct result

P.S. I assume following fields are of DATE data type: `Created_Date`, `DateWon`, `DateLost`

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, this is brilliant! I can't pretend to understand it but it worked perfectly.

I'll try to unpick it to understand it in more detail. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could left join 3 aggregate queries, then compute the cumulative sums:

```
select 
    c.mon
    sum(c.amount) over(order by c.mon) open,
    sum(w.amount) over(order by c.mon) won
    sum(l.amount) over(order by c.mon) loss
from ( 
    select date_trunc(month, create_date) mon, sum(amount) amount 
    from mytable 
    group by date_trunc(month, create_date)
) c
left join (
    select date_trunc(month, datewon) mon, sum(amount) amount 
    from mytable 
    group by date_trunc(month, datewon)
) w on w.mon = c.mon
left join (
    select date_trunc(month, datelost) mon, sum(amount) amount 
    from mytable 
    group by date_trunc(month, datelost)
) l on l.mon = c.mon
```

Comment: Thanks GMB, I see what you're doing there. I've marked Mikhail's as the answer, but this helped me understand how you'd tackle a problem like this in the future. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select yyyymm,
       sum(sum(case when iswon then amount else 0 end)) over (order by yyyymm) as won,
       sum(sum(case when isloss then amount else 0 end)) over (order by yyyymm) as loss
from (select t.*, 
             date_trunc(month, coalesce(datewon, datelost, created_date) as yyyymm,
      from t
     ) t
group by yyyymm;
```